# yahoo finance cookie not valid

Tags: api, cookies, finance, yahoo

since yesterday seems that something has changed on Yahoo Finance API.

Before
[link](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/$%7BTICKER%7D?period1=$%7BPERIOD_1%7D&period2=$%7BPERIOD_2%7D&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=$%7BCRUMB%7D)
Since Today
[link](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/$%7BTICKER%7D?period1=$%7BPERIOD_1%7D&period2=$%7BPERIOD_2%7D&interval=1d&events=history)
Yahoo finance, seems to have removed the CRUMB query param and, besides that, at cookie level, i would say that they have introduced new param.

The API returns a 401, randomly but consistently, saying that the cookie is invalid.

I've tested:

- Inject the cookie as is from navigator.
- Modifying PRF cookie parameter, and set it to requested TICKER.
- Requesting 1 ticker, at time. Note that although I request 1 at time, throttling obviously is to high for a human, and easily can be detected as a robot by a middle-ware.

But all tests ends on same result; the error on my point of view does nothing to do with the cookie since sometimes Yahoo finances responses with 200 and the data, and maybe is related with throttling.

Anyone with the same problem and knows how to sort it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I've already tested, setting COOKIES to None/Null, and the result is exactly the same; sometimes works, but consistentlly returns 401 cookie not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, is related with throttling. Reducing requests to <5it/s makes it work.

Comment: I'm having the same issue after some alternate code failed and I started to download the csv through html. What is 5it/s? Essentially how long do you wait in between calls?  I'm not sure if they temp blocked me for downloading faster or what(I can now download but not sure how fast I can go as I waited an hour). Pretty sure I was doing a max of a maybe 2 or 3 a second. Maybe there are different limits such as X/s and Y/hr?